Calculate the radius, speed and sink rate of a glider with a specific bank angle in a steady turn
For a glider, what is the radius, speed and sink rate of a glider with a specific bank angle in a steady turn while flying at minimum sink speed -> speed where $\frac{{c_L}^3}{{c_D}^2}$ is max.
I came across some similar questions, but none of them answered it for me.
What I got is a glider with constant gravitational force $g$, wing area $S$ and mass $m$. I also know the minium sink velocity $u_{sink_{min}}$ for a given wing loading and the corresponding speed $u$. The $c_L$ to $c_D$ graph is also known.
I know that the radius is calculated with:
$$ r = \frac{{u_{turn}}^2}{g \cdot tan(\phi)}$$
What I cannot get my head arround is the fact, that the velocity $u_{turn}$ needed in that turn is also dependend on $\phi$. How is the velocity $u_{turn}$ calculated than?
My first thought was that it is dependend on square root of the load factor $n=\frac{1}{\cos(\phi)}$. Because of the higher wing loading/load factor, the needed lift $F_L$ is higher and so you must fly faster.
And how can I calculate the $u_{sink_{min}}$ (sink rate) in a turn than ? Is it as simple as:
$$u_{sink_{turn}}=u_{sink_{min}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos(\phi)}}$$
It felt too easy, thats why I ask you guys to help me solve this problem for my thesis.
I know that $F_L=F_G \cdot \cos(\gamma)$, but for simplicity and small glide paths in gliding I assumed that $\cos(\gamma)=1$.
The second question to truly solve this question is to also take the uplift/winds in consideration because updrafts varies with distance from the center of the thermal. Maybe someone also has a smart idea for that.
Many greetings and thanks to all of you in advance
My used values (ASK23):
$m=330$;
$g=9.81$;
$\epsilon=0.93$;
$AR=17.44$;
$c_{D0}=0.0069$;
$S=12.9$;
$u_{sink_{min}}=0.66$ @74km/h in straight flight
Edit 1:
I plotted $v_{sink}$ over $\phi$ with Peter Kämpf first formula. The graph looks rather unrealistic.

Edit 2: I plotted $v_{sink}$ over $\phi$ again with Peter Kämpf editted formula. The graph looks better now, but I still think the sink rate is way to low. In reality much more people would fly with a higher bank angle when the degredation of the $v_{sink}$ is like that in that graph.

After looking at this graph for awhile, i realised that my first mathematical approach with $u_{sink_{turn}}=u_{sink_{min}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos(\phi)}}$ looks rather similiar.


From my own soaring experience in an ASW20, the bank angle is mostly determined by the diameter and strength of the thermal more than that kind of mathematical analysis.  Once I think I'm near the core, or if the thermal is small, I normally go right to 45 deg or a little more, and I go a bit faster than min sink, around 48-50kt and trim it out. I find it settles into a groove that is easy to maintain and I get better climb performance. If I have to I'll go right to 60 deg to stay in the core lift. In other words, the smallest circle that can be flown consistently.

@RalphJ in general though once you are cored you bank at about 45 deg or more unless you are sharing space with somebody else and must adjust to maintain position, or are sniffing out the best part. Most glider pilots don't bank steep enough.

Perhaps my question was unclear. I want to plot/calculate the graph of the radius versus $\phi$, the sink rate versus $\phi$, and the speed in a turn versus $\phi$.
Let me know if you’d like help with calculating or plotting these!

Think of min sink rate as being a parameter associated with one particular angle-of-attack. It's the angle-of-attack that maximizes (Cl^3)/(Cd^2). The airspeed associated with this angle-of-attack will vary according to the square root of the load factor.  So will the sink rate.  This is an an approximation because it doesn't take it to account that the "relative wind" is actually curved in circling flight, and the fuselage doesn't "bend" to conform, so you are imposing a smaller "decalage" angle between wing and tail, at least from the airflow's perspective, than would exist in linear flight.

(At least in case of fixed horizontal tail rather than all-moving tailplane.)  Compensate as needed w/ elevator, and that's why the stick is further aft in circling flight than at the same a-o-a in linear flight.  Which will have some theoretical effect on efficiency, sink rate, etc.  Another way to look at the same issue is to look at the "pitch damping" effect imposed by the aircraft's (nose-up) pitch rotation rate while circling.  So the aerodynamics of circling are not exactly the same (just with speed scaled up as per wing loading) as the aerodynamics of linear flight.

The distribution of updraft velocity across the thermal will affect your choice of bank angle but shouldn't affect the equations relating bank angle, airspeed, and sink rate relative to the airmass.  If you want to incorporate sink rate relative to the ground into your model, then yes you have to give some thought to the distribution of updraft velocity across the thermal.  I would say-- "good luck with that", sounds very complicated, not sure there is any widely accepted model of what this looks like in reality.

If you want to give more thought toward aerodynamic effects related specifically to circling flight (and I'm not saying you really should) then see https://wingsandwheels.com/blog/post/thermalling-in-a-slight-slip, and search aviation stack exchange for some answers I've written referencing Holighaus.

Does this answer your question?

You have probably missed the right answers so far.
Minimum sink speed is indeed achieved at the maximum of c$_L$³/c$_D$², as proven in this answer. Note that for a very high aspect ratio wing this polar point might be unachievable because it requires a rather high maximum lift coefficient.
Now for the velocity: When banking, only part of the lift force can counteract gravity because the remainder is needed to provide the centripetal force needed for circling. As you write, flight speed needs to go up in proportion to the inverse of the cosine of the bank angle. Start with the simple connection between angular speed $\Omega$ and flight speed $v$:
$$v = \Omega \cdot R$$
with the radius of the turn $R$:
$$R = \frac{2\cdot m\cdot\frac{n_z}{\sqrt{n_z^2-cos\gamma}}}{\rho\cdot c_L\cdot S}$$
the angular speed $\Omega$:
$$\Omega = \sqrt{\frac{(n_z^2-cos\gamma)\cdot g\cdot c_L\cdot\rho\cdot S}{2\cdot m\cdot n_z}}$$
and use the lift coefficient at minimum energy loss when replacing $R$ in the equation above:
$$c_L = \sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot\epsilon}$$
and the load factor $n_z$:
$$n_z = \frac{1}{cos\Phi}$$
Now we have all in place to calculate the flight speed at the given bank angle $\Phi$:
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{cos\Phi}\right)^2-cos\gamma\right)\cdot g\cdot \sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot \epsilon}\cdot\rho\cdot S}{2\cdot m\cdot \frac{1}{cos\Phi}}} \cdot \frac{2\cdot m\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{cos\Phi}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{cos\Phi}\right)^2-cos\gamma}}}{\rho\cdot \sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot \epsilon}\cdot S}$$
cancelling terms allows us to further simplify the speed equation to
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot m\cdot g\cdot\frac{1}{cos\Phi}}{\rho\cdot \sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot \epsilon}\cdot S}}$$
which is basically the definition equation of the lift coefficient written in an odd form and for the minimum sink condition. The corresponding sink speed $v_z$ is now:
$$v_z = v\cdot\frac{c_D}{c_L} = \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot m\cdot g\cdot \frac{1}{cos\Phi}}{\rho\cdot S\cdot\sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot\epsilon}}} \cdot\frac{4\cdot c_{D0}}{\sqrt{3\cdot c_{D0}\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot\epsilon}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{32\cdot\sqrt{c_{D0}}\cdot m\cdot g}{cos\Phi\cdot\rho\cdot S\cdot\sqrt{(3\cdot\pi\cdot AR\cdot\epsilon)^3}}}$$
The results for an ASK-23 are plotted below:

Graph of speed, radius, load factor and sink speed in SI units. Since the z axis is oriented downwards, a sink speed is positive.
Nomenclature:
$c_L \:\:\:$ lift coefficient
$\epsilon \:\:\:\:\;$  Oswald factor
$g \:\:\:\:\;$  gravitational acceleration 
$n_z \:\:\:$  load factor 
$m \:\:\:\:$  airplane mass
$\pi \:\:\:\:\;$  3.14159…
$\Phi \:\:\:\:$  roll angle
$\rho \:\:\:\:\:$  air density
$R \:\:\:\;$  radius of the circle
$S \:\:\:\;$  wing area
$v \:\:\:\:\:$  flight speed
$v_z \:\:\:$  sink speed

Isn't the $c_L^³$/$c_d^2$ using the assumption of straight flight? in a curve $L=W$ does not hold anymore, so minimum sink speed doesn't occur at max $c_L^³$/$c_d^2$?

@Peter Kämpf Thank you for you answer. Thats exactly what I need. Can you maybe share a bit more of the intermediate steps to get the final formula, so I can fully understand what you did there?

@ROIMaison I dont know If this really changes in a turn. But a ascpect I also need to look at.

@ROIMaison In a turn lift is L = m·g·n$_z$ and the ratio stays the same. L = W is a simplification.
